# Javascript reduce() only takes 2 array elements into account

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get the average rating of all "Drama"-movies in a certain array.
So my plan was to 
1.) do some "filter" function to get an array with all "Drama"-movies
2.) do a "reduce" function which accumulates all rating and divide the return value by the length of the "Drama"-array.

The first step works, however, when I try to make the "reduce"-function, it returns  a NaN every time my "Drama"-array contains more than 2 elements. If I test it with 2 elements, it works. I am really confused, for some reason the "rate" of the 3rd element are not treated as numeric values anymore.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

```js
var movies = [{
    title: 'Fargo',
    year: '1994',
    director: 'Frank Darabont',
    duration: '2h 52min',
    genre: ['Drama'],
    rate: '7.78'
  },
  {
    title: 'Terminator',
    year: '1994',
    director: 'Frank Darabont',
    duration: '2h 52min',
    genre: ['Drama', 'Crime'],
    rate: '9.36'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
    year: '1994',
    director: 'Frank Darabont',
    duration: '2h 52min',
    genre: ['Drama'],
    rate: '8.5'
  },
  {
    title: 'Titanic',
    year: '1994',
    director: 'Frank Darabont',
    duration: '2h 52min',
    genre: ['Romance'],
    rate: '2.5'
  }
]

function dramaMoviesRate(arr) {
  let drama = (arr.filter(movie => movie.genre.includes('Drama')))
  if (drama.length >= 2) {
    const total = drama.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => parseFloat(accumulator.rate) + parseFloat(currentValue.rate))
    return Math.round((total / drama.length) * 100) / 100
  } else if (drama.length === 1) {
    return (parseFloat(drama[0].rate))
  }
}
console.log(dramaMoviesRate(movies))
```

Answer (score 5):

In [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) set [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters)  as `0` and parse only the next value(`currentValue.rate`) otherwise, on second iteration onwards `accumulator.rate` would be [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) and return value would be [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

```
const total = drama.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) =>  accumulator + parseFloat(currentValue.rate), 0)
```